# How to read data from .txt file separated by a whitespace using php

Tags: php

I have the following code merely for test purposes

```
$file = "test.txt";

$resource = fopen($file,"w");

$content = file($file);

fclose($resource);
```

the content in **$file** is as follows

```
1 5 2 6 142423 2 435 231 5 252 3224 325 54 232
```

I've read `file()`returns content inside an array by **newlines**. What I really wanted was to push this into an array but I don't know how can I establish a pattern in **PHP**. Any help on this one? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [explode](http://php.net/explode):

```
$file = "test.txt";
$content = file_get_contents($file);
$arr = explode(" ", $content);
print_r($arr);
```

The output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 142423
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 435
    [7] => 231
    [8] => 5
    [9] => 252
    [10] => 3224
    [11] => 325
    [12] => 54
    [13] => 232
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're mixing things up, if you want it as an array, function [file](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.file.php)

```
 $file = "./test.txt";
 $content = file_get_contents($file, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
 $array_contents = explode(" ", $content);
```

Comment: I see... strangely enough $content is giving out as NULL... why use the flag FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH?

Comment: Actually, it will use your include path if this is set [set_include_path](http://fr.php.net/set_include_path). If this is the case, with this flag, your file has to be on your include path, without this it will take the file in the same dir.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file_content = file("text.txt");

foreach($file_content as &$line){
    $line = explode(" ", $line);
}
```